# what does type conversion actually do in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

I had this question on my interview. Code example:

```
NSString *str = ...;
NSDate *date = (NSDate *)str;
NSLog(@"%d", [date timeintervalsince1970]);
```

I understand that on the second line `date` variable stores object previously assigned to `str` without visible changes (I can send `NSString` messages to it and the app falls down on third line because `NSString` hasn't method `timeIntervalSince1970`).

The question is which "hidden" changes does compiler perform on the second line? (memory and e.t.c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It silences the compiler. You "override" the compiler's assumptions that an object is of certain type. Once you typecast, the compiler bases it's assumptions as if the object was of type you type-casted the object to.

In reality the object is still of type as it was before typecasting. 
Most of the time, the runtime will let you "eat your cake" painfully...for example unrecognised selectors, crashes...etc..

Comment: Casting does more in "C" languages, one example is casting an int to a float, this actually created a new data representation. The answer applies to a limited area of casting: casting pointers.

Comment: It seems they wanted to hear something additional about message sending in this case. But it is guess only

Comment: I mark this as an answer to close the question only. Everything you wrote is too evident to ask it.